How to sort a string that consists of only two different characters using recursion in Java?
So, my question is in the title. The only allowed methods are length(), isEmpty(), charAt() and substring(). We cant use any new methods, no loops or arrays
public class sortedString {

    private static String orderCharGroups(String text) {
        if (text.isEmpty()){
            return "";
        }

        char smallerChar = text.charAt(0);

        if(text.charAt(0) == smallerChar){
            return smallerChar + orderCharGroups(text.substring(1));
        } else {
         return orderCharGroups(text.substring(1)) + smallerChar;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(orderCharGroups(""));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("1"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("12"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("1212"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("abbaaababbaa"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("ABBA"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("11221122"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("AAAAAA"));
        System.out.println();

    }
}

The problem is that the smaller char gets updated at each iteration, so it just returns me my string. How can I make it so that this smallerChar doesn't get updated?

You are on the right track, but there are a couple of issues:
On this line you are comparing the first character to itself:
char smallerChar = text.charAt(0);
if (text.charAt(0) == smallerChar) {

Instead you should go ahead and recurse with the substring (omitting the first character) and compare the first character of the result to the original first character:
char first = text.charAt(0);
String substring = orderCharGroups(text.substring(1));
if (first <= substring.charAt(0)) {
    return first + substring;
} else {
    return substring + first;
}

You also need to change your base case so that you don't get a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception when doing text.substring(1):
if (text.length() <= 1) {
    return text;
}

Here is the full working example:
class SortedString {
    private static String orderCharGroups(String text) {
        if (text.length() <= 1) {
            return text;
        }

        char first = text.charAt(0);
        String substring = orderCharGroups(text.substring(1));
        if (first <= substring.charAt(0)) {
            return first + substring;
        } else {
            return substring + first;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups(""));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("1"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("12"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("1212"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("abbaaababbaa"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("ABBA"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("11221122"));
        System.out.println(orderCharGroups("AAAAAA"));
    }
}

Output:

1
12
1122
aaaaaaabbbbb
AABB
11112222
AAAAAA


Here is a possible solution, although it is not perfect, it passes the tests:
String orderCharGroups( String text, String b, String c ) {    
   if( text == null || text.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty() && c.isEmpty() ) {
      return "";
   }
   if( text.isEmpty() ) return b + c;
   String aux = text.substring( 0, 1 );
   if( b.isEmpty() ) b = aux;      
   else {
      if( b.charAt( 0 ) == aux.charAt( 0 ) ) b += aux;         
      else  c += aux;        
   }
   return orderCharGroups( text.substring( 1, text.length() ), b, c );
}

It passes the tests because in them, the first letter of each word is the smallest, otherwise, for example, an entry “baab” would return “bbaa”, which would force us to rewrite if( text.isEmpty() ) return b + c;, making it much more complicated.
